# Improve this code: List.Contains Regex without creating a new comparison object?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I threw down this code to implement a Regex variant of List.Contains() in LinqPad.  It unfortunately forces one to create an object to do the comparisons and of course static classes cannot implement interfaces.  Is there any way to achieve the same result without creating a separate object to do the compare?

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new List<string>();
    a.Add(" Monday ");
    a.Add(" Tuesday ");
    a.Add(" Wednesday ");
    a.Add(" Thursday ");
    a.Add(" Friday ");

    a.Contains(@"sday\s$", new ListRegexComparer() ).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class ListRegexComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{

    public bool Equals(string listitem, string regex)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(listitem, regex);
    }


    public int GetHashCode(string listitem)
    {
        return listitem.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Edit:

```
a.Any(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(?i)sday\s$")).Dump()
```

Nice, in-line way without creating objects to do it from Chris Tavares and Jean Hominal.

Comment: Please note that you are completely misusing the `IEqualityComparer` interface, as all the requirements in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154.aspx) for these methods are violated: "`Equals`" is neither reflexive (`Equals("a$", "a$") == false`), nor symetric (`Equals("a", "a?") == true` while `Equals("a?","a") == false`) nor transitive (`Equals("a", "a?") == true` and `Equals("a?", "[a][?]") == true` but `Equals("a", "[a][?]") == false`); as for `GetHashCode()`, it must be that `Equals(a, b) == true` implies `GetHashCode(a) == GetHashCode(b)`, but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex matcher = new Regex(@"sday\s$");
a.Any(s => matcher.IsMatch(s)).Dump();
```

Although I think you meant a different list method - [according to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) the List.Contains method doesn't take a comparer.

If you don't want to use Linq, then `a.Exists` will do the same thing using a method that's directly on List.

Comment: You should be able to use the method group syntax: `a.Any(matcher.IsMatch).Dump();`

Comment: Yeah, probably. I find the explicit lambda to be more readable, but that's a question of personal style I'm sure.

Comment: Also, he is probably using the LINQ [Contains extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the pointer, I forgot about that one.

Comment: @Dr.Zim: Why do you use the `matcher` object to call a [static method of the Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx)?

Comment: my mistake lol.  That was kind of the point of the question too.